# Cookie and WebSocket plugin for Jmeter

Tags: websocket, jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I use the https://github.com/kawasima/jmeter-websocket plugin for JMeter.

I have a *HTTP Cookie Manager* in my test tree. HTTP request samplers store and send the cookie from the cookie Manager.

But the websocket sampler does not send the cookie from the HTTP cookie manager.

Can someone explain how to make JMeter send cookies with websocket requests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to raise a bug on websocket plugin as the issue is in it.